# Place %s in a 0-9 10-19 etc. bracket

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have around 8k+ rows of data that is comparing numbers, and giving a % pulled.
Random example pulled out of the air...

```
Place Orders w/drink w/oDrink %w/oDrink
Mcdon   100    25       75       25%
```

My brackets are:

```
0-9
10-19
20-29
30-39
40-49
50-59
60-69
70-79
80-89
90+
```

The 25% would go into the 20-29 bracket. I am just trying to figure out if there is a function I can use to make it distinguish that?

Comment: That depends on your setup.  You can use MATCH() with just a list of the lower limits of each bracket.

Comment: Why does the value ***9*** exist in two different brackets ???

Comment: What about 19.5% where should that go?

Comment: Gary, that was a typo. They tend to happen time to time. Scott, it would go in the 10-19 bracket.

Comment: You just need the starting point for your bracket and use `VLOOKUP` with a `TRUE or 1` instead of `FALSE` on the 4th parameter.  Something similar to this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46433148/4388883)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a table with just the starting values and the desired output:

[image]

Then a simple VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2*100,G:H,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious, as it doesn't really matter, but why did you do 0-90 for the table, instead of 0-90% and not have the `E2*100` in the formula? Just personal preference?

Comment: @BruceWayne it was easier, since I had to create the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this UDF. Please enter code below in regular module.

```
Function BucketNumber(rng As Range) As String
    Dim strReturn As String

    Select Case rng.Value * 100
        Case 0 To 9.9999
            strReturn = "0-9"
        Case 10 To 19.9999
             strReturn = "10-19"
        Case 20 To 29.9999
             strReturn = "20-29"
        Case 30 To 39.9999
             strReturn = "30-39"
        Case 40 To 49.9999
             strReturn = "40-49"
        Case 50 To 59.9999
             strReturn = "50-59"
        Case 60 To 69.9999
             strReturn = "60-69"
        Case 70 To 79.9999
             strReturn = "70-79"
        Case 80 To 89.9999
             strReturn = "80-99"
        Case Else
             strReturn = "90+"
    End Select
    BucketNumber = strReturn
End Function
```

You can now use this formula in worksheets just like regular ones.

[image]

Comment: Your Select Case numbers may not be valid as the OP wanted *'The 25% would go into the 20-29 bracket'*. That would be **0.25**, not **25**.